# Shading a rectangle

Tags: matlab, plot, coordinates

Consider the rectangle formed by the vertices (0, 0), (0, 10), (1, 10), and (1, 0). How would I shade it red in MATLAB?

*Note.* For some reason, none of the mentioned shadings [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/fillpattern.html) works.

Comment: Start by telling what have you tried (with code) and what were the results.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Clearly, if I had an idea of what to do, I wouldn't ask. I already mentioned that I tried looking it up and found something which didn't work. Your comment would be more appropriate in a Math.StackExchange post where someone should show work. This type of question -- well, I either know how to do it or I don't.

Comment: When you are saying "is not working", I am assuming you have tried something to get it to work. If you haven't, you should say "I haven't tried", not "it's not working".

Comment: To quote exactly what I wrote: 

"For some reason, none of the mentioned shadings here [link was provided] works." Well, if you click on the link, you will find code which should work when copied and pasted into the command line. I tried copying it and it didn't work -- it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that for example with [`patch`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html):

```
vertices = [0 0; 0 10; 1 10; 1 0];
patch(vertices(1:end,1), vertices(1:end,2), [1 .2 .2], 'edgecolor', [0 0 0]);
    %// [1 .2 .2] is light red for the fill; [1 1 1] is black for the edge
axis([-1 2 -10 20]); %// set axis limits to properly see rectangle
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the +1! Let's say I wanted to do a more general case, where the vertices are (a, -h), (a, h), (a+1, h), and (a+1, -h). The first line would become: 

`vertices = [a -h; a h; a + 1 h; a + 1 -h];`

How would the second line change? Thanks again!

Comment: The second line would be the same. You only need to change the numbers if the second line depending on which colors you want. For example, `[1 1 1]` and `[0 0 1]` for bright red with blue edge